# How to correct this program? (EDITED)

Tags: c++

**(I just edited my post sorry for the confusions)** Can you help me with this code?  I was expecting an array of answer slots. 
    // 2-12-14.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    int x = 0;
    char answer[25];
    for (x = 0; x < 25; x++) {
        do {
            cout << x + 1 << ".";
            scanf("%c", answer + x);
        } while (
            (answer[x] != 'A')
            && (answer[x] != 'B')
            && (answer[x] != 'C')
            && (answer[x] != 'D')
        );  
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the second output giving double numbers?

```
scanf("%c", answer + x);
```

When I replaced it with:

```
cin>>answer[x]; //this was previously cout<<answer[x] **sorry for the confusion**
```

...it works fine.

Comment: `scanf` reads input. `printf` is the approximate equivalent for output. But as you are writing `C++`, just stick with `std::cout`.

Comment: What do you think `cout << x + 1 << ".";` will do? Or what did you want it to do?

Comment: Sorry! I meant `cin >> answer[x]` not `cout << answer[x]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the second output giving double numbers?

Because you are giving double input. If you type "A<enter>" then the first character is `A` and the second character is the enter. That causes your loop to output then repeat, resulting in two outputs.

Since your code does *not* expect an enter between inputs, you should not type one. Type all the answers on the same line and the code will work fine. Alternatively, change the code to **silently** ignore line ending characters.

Comment: Sorry! I meant `cin >> answer[x]` not `cout << answer[x]`

Comment: Answer is still the same. If the user types `A<enter>`, you will read two characters, A and enter.